# Adding numbers to analog clock Processing

Tags: processing, clock

make a 24 hour clock. What makes it 24 hour is the clock face will count up from zero hour to 23. But the clock face has only either the AM numbering of the hours or the PM numbering of the hours shown at any one time. The AM numbering is from 0 to 11. The PM is from 12 to 23
I need use the drawNum code and i can't get it to work,
this is the code i have so far...

```
float x[], y[]; 
float diam;  
color c[];
int n; //number of balls 

void setup()
{
  size (500, 500);
  colorMode(HSB);
  background(0);
  frameRate(1);
  x = new float [n];
  y = new float [n];
}

void draw()
{
  float h, m, s; 
  float radius; 
  float cx, cy;


  float clockface; 
  float hoursRadius, minutesRadius, hoursTick, secondsRadius, minutesTick;

  radius = min(height/2.0, width/2.0); 
  cx = width/2.0;
  cy = height/2.0;  

  clockface = radius * 0.9;
  hoursRadius = radius * 0.5;
  minutesRadius = radius * 0.65;
  secondsRadius = radius * 0.72;
   hoursTick = radius * 0.04;
   minutesTick = hoursTick * 0.5;

  // get time 
  s = second(); 
  m = minute(); 
  h = hour()%12 + m/60.0; 

  //draw clock face 
  fill(40);
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  ellipse(cx, cy, clockface, clockface); 

  //
  drawHand(cx, cy, s*6.0, secondsRadius, 2); 
  drawHand(cx, cy, m*6.0, minutesRadius, 3); 
  drawHand(cx, cy, h*30.0, hoursRadius, 5); 


for ( int i=0; i<60; i++) {
   if (i%5==0) {
     drawNum(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, 10, 0);
   } else {
     drawNum(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, 5, 23);
    }
  }

  // draw the ticks
  for ( int i=0; i<60; i++) {
    if (i%5==0) {
      drawTick(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, 10);
    } else {
      drawTick(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, 5);
    }
  }
}
void drawTick( float x, float y, 
  float angle, float len, 
  float weight) {
  fill(angleToColor(angle));
  noStroke();
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, 
    y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len, 
    weight, weight) ;
}
void drawHand( float x, float y, 
  float angle, float len, 
  float weight) {

  strokeWeight(weight); 
  stroke(angleToColor(angle)); 
  line(x, y, 
    x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, 
    y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len);
}

color angleToColor(float angle) { 
  return color(map(angle, 0, 360, 0, 255), 255, 255);
}

void drawNum(float x,float y, 
  float angle, float len, 
  float tsize, int num) {
float i;  
     textSize(36);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  for (num = 0; num < 12; num++) {
     int hoursNum = (x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, 
    y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len, 
    num, num)) ;;


 }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's your question? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how to get the numbers to appear on the clock face.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the number into a string (text) to display it.  This is done with function `str(arg)` which returns a value of type `String`.  The argument `arg` can be an int, float, char, byte or boolean type.

The function for drawing text is `text( s, x, y )` where `s` is the string to display and `x` and `y` are the location.

**EDIT:**

The `hour()` function returns hours on a 24-hour clock, measured from 0-23 instead of 1-24.  Right-click on the function in the Processing window and select "Find in Reference" to see the details. The code `hour()%12` is taking the hour value modulo 12, which means when the value reached 12 it cycles back to zero, and values 12-23 are reported as 0-11.

Comment: would you by chance know how to get the clock face to read 0-11 then 12-23?

Comment: Answer edited, though I don't really understand your question.  If you want the clock hours to indicate 0-11 when it's morning time, and then indicate 12-23 when afternoon time, you need an `if()` statement to check whether `hour()` is greater than or equal to 12, that is, whether or not the current time is after noon.